# get the previous and next value that is not null in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

See the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2'],
                    "ORDER":['1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4'],
                    "TYPE":['Started a Project',None,'Edited a Project','Closed a Project','Started a Project',None,None,'Closed a Project']})
# print results
print(df.head(10))

# a function to label the first type 1 for each ID sorted by line
def PREV_TYPE(row):
    return row.name

def NEXT_TYPE(row):
    return row.name    

# add the label in the dataframe
df['PREV_TYPE'] = df.apply (lambda row: PREV_TYPE(row), axis=1)
df['NEXT_TYPE'] = df.apply (lambda row: PREV_TYPE(row), axis=1)

# print results
print(df.head(10))
```

I have been trying to create two extra columns `PREV_TYPE` and `NEXT_TYPE` to obtain the next and previous `TYPE` **which doesn't equal** `None`. This has to be done separately for each `ID` (set).

Current output:

```
  ID ORDER               TYPE  PREV_TYPE  NEXT_TYPE
0  1     1  Started a Project          0          0
1  1     2               None          1          1
2  1     3   Edited a Project          2          2
3  1     4   Closed a Project          3          3
4  2     1  Started a Project          4          4
5  2     2               None          5          5
6  2     3               None          6          6
7  2     4   Closed a Project          7          7
```

Desired output:

```
  ID ORDER               TYPE           PREV_TYPE          NEXT_TYPE
0  1     1  Started a Project                None   Edited a Project
1  1     2               None   Started a Project   Edited a Project
2  1     3   Edited a Project   Started a Project   Closed a Project
3  1     4   Closed a Project    Edited a Project               None
4  2     1  Started a Project                None   Closed a Project
5  2     2               None   Started a Project   Closed a Project
6  2     3               None   Started a Project   Closed a Project
7  2     4   Closed a Project   Started a Project               None
```

How would I accomplish that in my `PREV_TYPE` and `NEXT_TYPE` functions? I am looking for the fastest way to do this. But will also welcome any other way to do it.

Comment: df.groupby('ID').TYPE.shift();df.groupby('ID').TYPE.shift(-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy the row with a [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) of one down (previous) or one up (next) while grouping on `ID`:

```py
df['PREV_TYPE'] = df.groupby('ID')['TYPE'].shift(1)
df['NEXT_TYPE'] = df.groupby('ID')['TYPE'].shift(-1)
```

```py
  ID ORDER               TYPE          PREV_TYPE         NEXT_TYPE
0  1     1  Started a Project                NaN               NaN
1  1     2                NaN  Started a Project  Edited a Project
2  1     3   Edited a Project                NaN  Closed a Project
3  1     4   Closed a Project   Edited a Project               NaN
4  2     1  Started a Project                NaN               NaN
5  2     2                NaN  Started a Project               NaN
6  2     3                NaN                NaN  Closed a Project
7  2     4   Closed a Project                NaN               NaN
```

Then [`.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) (going down) or [`.bfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) (going up), again grouped:

```py
df['PREV_TYPE'] = df.groupby('ID')['PREV_TYPE'].ffill()
df['NEXT_TYPE'] = df.groupby('ID')['NEXT_TYPE'].bfill()
```

```py
  ID ORDER               TYPE          PREV_TYPE         NEXT_TYPE
0  1     1  Started a Project                NaN  Edited a Project
1  1     2                NaN  Started a Project  Edited a Project
2  1     3   Edited a Project  Started a Project  Closed a Project
3  1     4   Closed a Project   Edited a Project               NaN
4  2     1  Started a Project                NaN  Closed a Project
5  2     2                NaN  Started a Project  Closed a Project
6  2     3                NaN  Started a Project  Closed a Project
7  2     4   Closed a Project  Started a Project               NaN
```